# Change scroll speed

Tags: scroll, sprite-kit, nstimeinterval

```
 var speed: CGFloat = 5

 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

 var move = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: node.position.x, y: -(self.frame.height)), duration: NSTimeInterval(speed))
 var reset = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: node.position.x, y: self.frame.height ), duration: 0)

        var scroll = SKAction.sequence([move, reset])
        node.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(scroll))
    }



    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

    speed++
     println(speed)
}
```

I have a node that i want to scroll, and i want it's speed changes depending on the player touch, my problem is when the player touch the value indeed increases but the node itself keeps the same initial value. I also tried changing in the update method and that didn't work either.
How to solve this ?

Comment: you cant change an action after you create it.  it's going to save speed at that moment. it disregards future changes.   you should move your track in your update loop.  dont use actions in this case

Comment: If u'm not going to use actions, then how will i make it scroll ? have you done anything like this before ?

Comment: yes of course.  you can just animate using a sprites position.  no need for action.  check out this tutorial.  it will help you  https://www.codefellows.org/blog/simple-ios-sprite-kit-game-tutorial   look at the section on scrolling background

Comment: @hamobi - his code is in Swift but your tutorial link is in Obj-C.

Comment: Thank You hamobi, 
sangoni, Obj-C is not a problem :)